# General questions about std::variant

Tags: c++, coding-style, c++17, variant

I had some questions about the new std::variant type. I considered using it as a typesafe alternative to union. I wrote some test code which should compile in an online compiler. I have not found a lot of information regarding storage of types like std::array in std::variant. Raw buffer storage (e.g uint8_t [4]) does not appear to be possible with std::variant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <variant>
#include <array>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdlib>
using parameters_t = std::variant<uint32_t, std::array<uint8_t, 4>>;

void setComParams(parameters_t& comParameters_, uint8_t value);

int main()
{
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> test;
    parameters_t comParameters = test; // can I assign the array here directly in some way?
    auto parametersArray = std::get_if<std::array<uint8_t, 4>>(&comParameters);
    if(parametersArray == nullptr) {
        exit(0);
    }

    auto & parameterReference1 = *parametersArray; //so I can use [] indexing
    parameterReference1[1] = 5;
    parameterReference1[3] = 6;
    std::cout << "I should be 5: " << (int)(*parametersArray)[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I should be 5: " << (int)parameterReference1[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I should be 6: " << (int)(*parametersArray)[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I should be 6: " << (int)parameterReference1[3] << std::endl;
    setComParams(comParameters, 10);
    std::cout << "I should be 10: "<< (int)(*parametersArray)[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I should be 10: "<< (int)parameterReference1[1] << std::endl;

    comParameters = 16; // this should be an uint32_t now
    auto parametersArray2 = std::get_if<std::array<uint8_t, 4>>(&comParameters);
    if(parametersArray2 == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Everything in order" << std::endl;
    }

    uint32_t * parameterNumber = std::get_if<0>(&comParameters); // using index now
    *parameterNumber = 20;
    std::cout << "I should be 20: "<< (int)*parameterNumber << std::endl;
    setComParams(comParameters,30);
    std::cout << "I should be 30: "<< (int)*parameterNumber << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void setComParams(parameters_t &comParameters_, uint8_t value) {
    auto comParametersArray = std::get_if<std::array<uint8_t, 4>>(&comParameters_);
    if(comParametersArray == nullptr) {
        auto comParameterValue = std::get_if<uint32_t>(&comParameters_);
        if(comParameterValue != nullptr) {
            *comParameterValue = value;
        }
    }
    else {
        auto & arrayReference = *comParametersArray;
        arrayReference[1] = value;
    }
}
```

Just to be sure I understood everything correctly: If I use std::get, I always receive a copy, 
which means no matter how I do it, I cant modify the actual value of variant. Do I always have to
use std::get_if in that case? 
Furthermore, is there any significant code bloat or overhead when using std::variant when compared to unions? Especially because I'm essentially using POD types (a union of uint32_t and uint8_t[4]).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Um `get` *never* returns a copy. There is no form of `get`, for `variant`, `tuple`, `std::array`, or any other type that `std::get` is overloaded for, that returns a *copy* of the object in question. I have no idea how you got the idea that `get` copies something, particularly when it's right there in the signature of the function.

Comment: I used get instead of get_if in the setComParams() function and the value in main() did not change. Maybe the mistake was somewhere else though.

Comment: @Spacefish Your code runs fine and gives the output you say you want: https://godbolt.org/z/CFvM9q

Comment: Okay, you're right. I wrote auto paramArray = std::get ... instead of auto & paramArray = std::get before trying std::get_if so I think that was the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign/initialize a `std::variant` directly with a prvalue of the type that you want to emplace:

```
parameters_t comParameters = std::array<uint8_t, 4>{};
```

although this zero-initializes the array in contrast to your code.

If you want to avoid the copy/move construction involved in this, you can use

```
parameters_t comParameters(std::in_place_type<std::array<uint8_t, 4>>);
```

for initialization or

```
comParameters.emplace<std::array<uint8_t, 4>>();
```

for assignment.

Both still zero-initialize the `std::array` though. As far as I am aware there is currently no way to default-initialize an object in a `std::variant`.

`std::get_if` returns a *pointer* to the the object in the `std::variant`. It never makes a copy of the object.

Instead of `std::get_if`, you could also use `std::get`. `std::get` will just throw an exception if you try to access the wrong type and returns a *reference* to the contained object. It never copies the object either.:

```
auto& parameterReference1 = std::get<std::array<uint8_t, 4>>(comParameters);
```

Built-in array types or reference types or function types are not allowed in the `std::variant` type list, because the types are required to satisfy the concept of being destructible, meaning that the expression

```
t.~T()
```

where `t` is of type `T` must be well-formed. This is not true for built-in arrays, but for pretty much all other sensible object types.